# Trying to programmatically set select option value not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to programmatically set a select list option value as being selected.

```
<script>
                if(typeof localStorage.me !== "undefined") {
                    console.log("test");
                    $("#business").val(localStorage.me);
                }
                if(typeof localStorage.partner !== "undefined") {
                    $("#partner-business").val(localStorage.partner);
                }

                $("#page-main").on("change", "#business", function(event) {
                    localStorage.setItem("me", $("#business").val());
                });
                $("#page-main").on("change", "#partner-business", function(event) {
                    localStorage.setItem("partner", $("#partner-business").val());
                });
            </script>
            <div class="content" data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <h3 class="select center-h3">I am a:</h3>
                    <select name="business" id="business">
                        <option value="technical">Technical</option>
                        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <h3 class="select center-h3">My partner is a:</h3>
                    <select name="partner-business" id="partner-business">
                        <option value="technical">Technical</option>
                        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to set it based on the option value, but this doesn't seem to work.

How do I set it by the option value and not the name inside the option tags?

Comment: you have two on change events for `#business`. Shouldn't one be for `#partner-business`

Comment: Thank you. Fixed it. Though I don't think that's the problem. Neither of them are working.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console ? Also try placing the script below the divs (before body tag ends)

Comment: You code works http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/68dtry7o/, Just for confimartion, Are you sure you have wrapped your code in doument-ready handler. Also there is a parent with id `#page-main`?

Comment: Putting the script below the divs made it work.

Comment: There is a parent with #page-main, and I did not wrap my code in a document-ready handler. I was under the impression that that did not work like it normally does in jQuery Mobile pages.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander, Wrap your code in document-ready handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap code in [document-ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler. Apart from that you code works.

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Your code
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/68dtry7o/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified method of doing the same thing, using `$(this)` instead of querying the dom, for future reference.

```js
if(localStorage.me) $("#business").val(localStorage.me);
if(localStorage.partner) $("#partner-business").val(localStorage.partner);

$("#business").on("input", function() {
    localStorage.me = $(this).val();
});
$("#partner-business").on("input", function() {
    localStorage.partner = $(this).val();
});
```